# О назначении на должность военрука + винительный или родительный

Tags: морфология, родительный-или-винительный

"О назначении на должность военрука" + ФИО - в винительнм или родительном падеже?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы поменяла местами: О назначении Иванова И.И. на должность военрука. Что касается падежа, то практически - никакой разницы для одушевленных существительных нет: винительный совпадает с родительным.(Кого?чего? - р.п. Кого?Что? - В.п.).  Назначить кого? что? - винительный. О назначении кого? чего? - родительный.

Comment: Что ж Вы вопросы дублируете? В Вашем случае: назначить Петрова Илью, но о назначении Петрова Ильи.

Answer (score 1):

Разумеется, падеж возможен только родительный. Несколько забавно выглядит аргумент, опирающийся на совпадение падежей.

Answer (score 0):

Переходный глагол "назначить" требует винительного падежа: назначить кого? - Илью.
Существительные винительным падежом не "управляют", тут требуется родительный: назначение кого? - Ильи. Слежовательно: о назначении на должность военрука Петрова Ильи 
Ефимовича, Смирновой Светланы Савельевны.